# Windows X-Server for ssh -X?

Tags: windows-7, x-server

I'm planning on SSH-ing into my ubuntu machine from my windows 7 machine with putty. I would like to be able to get X to work. Are there any viable X-servers for windows 7?

Comment: exact duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/13855/x-server-for-windows

Comment: but that's on a different website, is that not allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) is a nice, free and open-source option.

[Exceed](http://connectivity.opentext.com/products/exceed-products.aspx) is not free, but is a very nice option as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can run x in cygwin.  Then you don't need putty either....

Comment: when installing cygwin, be sure to install both the ssh and the X packages. I know X is not installed by default.